# service get killed when screen is off in some devices

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

I have seen many pages about this problem but didn't help me.
I have a service that should run in background even when the screen is off.

but some android devices (like many huawei phones) have battery care stuff that can kill service when screen is off, and android 6 has that option (keep running after screen off) but user should give that permission himself.

I see that telegram service get killed too, but how whatsapp service doesn't stop even when the screen is off.

this is my service in androidManifest

```
<service android:name=".myservice" />
```

is there any option in manifest that can keep service running when the screen is off? I can't use sticky-services because it runs over and over after screen turns on but my service should start once!

or any other solution for this problem?? thanks!

Comment: Give some more context like what is your service doing running in background? As per the documentation, service can be killed anytime because of many reasons and one of them is battery optimisation. So, again, why do you need your service be running even screen is off?

Comment: Also, on Android 8.0+, unless your service is a foreground service, it will only run for ~1 minute anyway. So, start by making your service be a foreground service, and see if that helps. But, in general, processes do not live forever, and the sooner you design your app around that limitation, the more successful you will be. For example, the notion that "my service should only start once" is impractical.

Comment: every time my service get started, it post a request to the server. and it checks for some data from server in handler for every 10 seconds in 5 minutes and because of that it can't start over and over. when the service is running, user waits for some response from server and this data shows to the user with notification and broadcast. @manish-kumar

Comment: 5 mins are too much time for a service, so as commonsware suggested make it foreground. But i would suggest to use FCM here because android app is waiting for data to come from server. Check for data from server every 10 sec for 5 minutes will have significant effect on battery and data, so prefer FCM. Here is the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: unfortunately i can't use FCM because many customer smartphones in my city doesn't have the latest version of google play services and my service is sending some location information to my database too. @ManishKumar